# difference between fputs and puts in c

Tags: c, fgets, puts, fputs

please explain it to me that what is the  dfference between
`puts(string name)` and `fputs(string name,stdout)`

both of them have the same output especially when I use `fgets(string name,n,stdin)` for get std size of a string  for a safe code ,
but after that and for print to output , what is the  difference between them although both of them have the same output?

Comment: `puts` is equivalent to `fputs("",stdin)`, but with a newline character after the string.

Comment: You might want to read more about these functions in your books. Or a decent [`fputs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) and [`puts`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) reference.

Comment: @alex01011 I think you meant `fputs("",stdout)` because you cannot write to `stdin`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`puts` appends a newline to the string, and `fputs` doesn't.

Otherwise there is no difference, except of course that with `fputs` you can specify a different stream, while `puts` always writes to `stdout`.